# How do I display/hide an html message from a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

Currently, on my website the contact form is validated through a piece of JS (I know this is risky and i have now moved on to PHPMailer).

What is currently triggering the success or error message below my contact form is this part of javascript:

```
        if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendphpmailer.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
                    $('.error').hide()
                    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Now that I'm using PHPMailer I'd like the success/error messages below my contact form to be driven from the PHP file (and no longer the JS one as it sometimes return a success message even when the message was not sent), so I have tried this (without success). What is the issue?

```
$mail->Subject = "New message from " . $_POST['name'];
$mail->Body =  $_POST['message'];

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
             $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
             $('.error').hide()
             $('.success').fadeIn(1000);} 
else 
{
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
}
```

If it helps, here is the original full PHP code:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

//Enable SMTP debugging. 
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;                               
//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            
//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = "smtp.elasticemail.com";
//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = "web@dshsjjh.com";                 
$mail->Password = "***";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to 
$mail->Port = 2525;                                   

$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];

$mail->addAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("xyz@outlook.com");
$mail->addBCC("");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "New message from " . $_POST['name'];
$mail->Body =  $_POST['message'];

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
?>
```

And the HTML:

```
<section class="contact clearfix" id="contact">
  <div class="contact-container clearfix">
    <form class="clearfix" id="contactfrm" method="post" name="contactfrm">
      <div class="tagbox wow fadeInRightBig"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Formulaire de contact
      </div>
      <input class="_input-1 floatlabel" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Votre nom et prénom" type="text">
      <input class="_input-2 floatlabel" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Votre adresse e-mail" type="email">
      <textarea class="floatlabel" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Votre message et votre numéro de téléphone"></textarea>
      <button class="wow fadeInUp" name="submit" type="submit" value="Envoyer"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> ENVOYER&nbsp;</button>

    </form>

  </div>
</section>

<footer class="clearfix">
  <div class="success" style="display:none">
    Votre message a bien été envoyé! Merci
  </div>

  <div class="error" style="display:none;">
    E-mail non valide et/ou message vide
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: JS validation is fine, for the UX. For security you need to validate in your server side scripts (as well).

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that with my current JS I get a "success" message even when the message was not sent (I have tried to put an incorrect smtp password for test purpose)

Comment: May you share html code?

Answer (score 0):

`if you're using ajax to send and email with PHPMailer then you can not check $mail->send() in javascript file

what you need to do is the following
in php file

> return json_encode(['success' => $mail->send()]);

and in your ajax success function do this

```
success: function(response) {
                if(response.success)
                {
                   //success message
                }
                else
                {
                   //error message
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try but I'm not sure exactly where to put return json_encode(['success' => $mail->send()]);  in the PHP file? Instead of something else?

Comment: yeah in sendphpmailer.php file put it right after $mail->Body =  $_POST['message'];
alternativy you can do the following
$msgSent = $mail->send() //assumed that function returns boolean
and then
return json_encode(['success' => $msgSend]);

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sendphpmailer.php",
  data: dataString,
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(response) {
    if(response.status){
      /* success */
      $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
      $('.error').hide()
      $('.success').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);  
    }else{
      /* error occurred show to user */
      $('.success').hide();
      $('button[name="submit"]').show();
      $('.error').html(response.message).fadeIn(1000);
    }
  }
});
```

PHP response:

```
$response = array();
if(!$mail->send()) {
  $response = array('message'=>"Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo, 'status'=> 0);
} else {
  $response = array('message'=>"Message has been sent successfully", 'status'=> 1);
}

/* send content type header */
header('Content-Type: application/json');

/* send response as json */
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: thanks! but for some reason that does not work (no error message, no success message)

Comment: does ajax request sent to server?

Comment: Not sure... how can I check this?

Comment: Open network tab in dev tools open by pressing `F12` in chrome;

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to install chrome. Here is the link to test the form http://goo.gl/veo5If Do you have the possibility  to check if the ajax request is sent to the server?

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean there's an extra at the end? I have tried to remove one }); but still the same issue. Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/nryuk2o6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106845/discussion-between-itzmukeshy7-and-greg).

Comment: @Greg replace this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itzmukeshy7/0zoz77bc/) code with scripts.js file code, here are two problems you have missed `}` of if condition and forgot to close `$().ready` closing `});`

Comment: Thanks! Now the success msg works (and the msg is sent) but the error msg does not work (if you leave all the fields empty and click "send", nothing happens whereas you should see the error message)